# How do I make external links open in new window automatically with JS (with exception rule)?

Tags: javascript, class, hyperlink, rel, nofollow

For my question I was not able to find a solution so far.
What I want is a js script that will convert all external links on my site (page), so that they open in a new window (add target=_blank to the a tag).

For this I have found a simple script that does this and it works like a charm (credits: gist.github.com/wpscholar). However, I have no control on the output at all. And I think it would make sense to have a little control on which links are changed and which not. Here is the basic script:

```
/** Open all external links in a new window */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a')
    .filter('[href^="http"], [href^="//"]')
    .not('[href*="' + window.location.host + '"]')
    .attr('rel', 'nofollow noopener noreferrer')
    .attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Can anyone give me an example script on how to add an exception, for when the a tag has class=trusted? Where only the target attribute is set and the rel attribute is left empty.

```
<a href="https://somedomain.com/" class="trusted">anchor</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a href="https://somedomain.com/" class="trusted" target="_blank">anchor</a>
```

When class=trusted is not found, it should just execute the example script.

Many thanks and happy new year!

Comment: Simply add a second `.not()`, that filters out elements with that class …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add your class "trusted" to your jQuery selector with not() (as you done with the href) :

```
/** Open all external links in a new window */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a')
    .filter('[href^="http"], [href^="//"]')
    .not('[href*="' + window.location.host + '"]')
    .attr('rel', 'nofollow noopener noreferrer')
    .not('.trusted')
    .attr('target', '_blank');
});
```